# Mysql count on with nested inner queries in IF condition

Tags: mysql

I need to count the number of results for pagination.

Demo Query

```
select A.order_id, 
       IF(
          E.assign_date IS NOT NULL AND E.assign_date != '0000-00-00',  
          DATE_FORMAT(E.assign_date , '%d-%b-%y'),
          (select data from other tables with other conditions)
       ) AS assign_date, 
       .......
       where 
       .....
       and assign_date > 2013-08-01
```

Count Query which I am using

```
Select count(A.order_id) from order A, size B, production E ........... where ....... and assign_date > 2013-08-01
```

I need to add that if condition so I can count the results properly

**Longer Version**

I have checked the questions posted on SO, and couldnt find the answer. I am working on a page where I am showing pagination.

For pagination I have used the count, which is working. Count query is not having this condition.

For actual query I wish I could post my whole query over here but it is over 200+ lines if sorted well.

For pagination I am using the following query.

```
$strQuery = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(A.order_id)) AS totalRecs FROM $tbls WHERE $whereClause $WhereExt";
```

The `$tbls` and `$whereClause` are very long.

In `orders` table I m having `assing_on` date field, which shows that an order is assigned to some one for production. I have created the result list page from the data, and in PHP added check that if `assign_on` date is empty/null. If it is I am running another query to get estimated start date of production.

The estimated start date of production gets a date on number of calculations and parameters

1. Orders.estimated delivery date (this is set when posting the order)
2. mustReadyDate = estimated date - shipment buffer (another table) - vendor holidays (another 3 tables) - vendor weekends (another 2 tables)
3. totalDaysRequired for production = total length of order / Standard weave rate per day (another table)
4. muststartdate = mustReadyDate - totalDaysRequired;

Above four points are all in query, no PHP work involve

Data fetch query is having this condition and count query is not having this condition at the moment.

```
IF(
    E.assign_date IS NOT NULL AND E.assign_date != '$mysqlEmptyDate',  
    DATE_FORMAT(E.assign_date , '" . reporting_DateFormat . "'),
    ($mustLoomStartDateQry_fm)
) AS assign_date,
```

I need to add one more condition in where clause of count query to check if `aasign_date > one week from today` I just want to know how I can add such a long query in count part so I only execute on query.

** EDIT **

If any one is interested in viewing the full query http://pastebin.com/zqzbpEei but please I am providing you this only to give you the insight...

Comment: `When` where? I need count with IF ELSE conditioned.

Comment: WHEN can do the same as IF ELSE and is the standard.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of usage of `WHEN` in MySQL query?

Answer (score 0):

If You Need pagination so please try this one.......

```
$Query="select * from table_name_here where colunm_name='content_which_you_find'";
```

for example

```
$Query="select * from android where type='Casual'";
```

if you not need the condition so please remove it......

like `$Query="select * from android";`

now execute above query using this

```
$Result=mysql_query($Query);
```

now get total number of rows are selected using this

```
$TotalRows=mysql_num_rows($Result);

$onepage=9;
```

change above 9 to you like how much you want to display records in one page

now paste following code to get pagination

```
$d=($page-1)*$onepage;
$SqlQuery="select * from android where type='Casual' order by id desc LIMIT $d, $onepage";
$ResultSql=mysql_query($SqlQuery) or die("error1?");
```

now put loop to print data

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ResultSql))
{
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
}
```

now put below code

```
 for($i=1;$i<=$np;$i++)
{
echo "<a href='currnt_page_name_here.php?page=$i'> $i </a>";
}
```

Try now this if any error tell me

Comment: Sorry you miss read my question. my query is having if conditions, and in if conditions I am getting data from different tables. If i do `select * from...` as you suggested my query execution time is more than 60 seconds for only 50 records.